# PC on bootloop cannot access BIOS

Tags: windows-10, bios

I bought a new SSD today installed a fresh copy of Windows 10 on it and all the software I regularly use (Android studio, Netbeans, etc). I used the PC for about 2 hours and decided to set the boot priority to the new SSD (note: my old hard disk was disconnected since the new SSD was installed) and I set the priority to #1 for the SSD and #2 for my DVD drive.

My PC is now stuck in an infinite boot - reboot loop and will not even get to the stage where I can access the BIOS. Theres nothing I can do as it boots for say 2-3 seconds with black blank screen then turns off again and starts over.

I regret messing with bios now...

I tried cleaning RAM
Disconnected SSD and connected old HDD
Removed CMOS battery for 10+ mins
Tried to boot from windows flash drive
Checked for any lose connectors

PC just shuts off in seconds when I switch it on.

PC specs:

i5 3rd gen

Gigabyte GA-B75M-D3H

Corsair 8GB ram

Raidmax 500W PSU

Sapphire R9 270x

Thanks guys

Comment: Is there a disk in the dvd drive?

Comment: Nope, I just checked. It's empty.

Comment: The fact that replacing the SSD with the old HDD leads to me believe something may have been misplaced/dislodged/damaged in the process of installing the SSD. Check and make sure all connections are secure, no exposed metal making contact with bare components, etc.

Comment: Also, did you ground yourself protecting from ESD?

Comment: Yes @ ESD protection

Comment: I just checked all connectors and tightly seated them to make sure. I hear a roar in the fans when I switch it on, like an alternation from low to high rpm. Could it be power related?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43372/discussion-between-jatuttle0-and-dr-code).

Comment: Reinstall W10 clean, then disable hibernation when you get to the desktop, this will insure you can access the bios on boot.

Comment: @jatuttle0 Might be worth putting an answer in so every one else can benefit from your fine handy work you did with OP, not everyone will look at your discussion!

Answer (score 0):

As we had concluded in chat, it appears that your UEFI BIOS had somehow become corrupted (likely through no fault of your own).

The solution was found by doing BIOS recovery as explained in [this Tomshardware thread](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1736983/gigabyte-z77x-ud3h-boot-loop.html#11182503) and playing around with boot priority along with your windows recovery thumb drive.

From [our discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43372/discussion-between-jatuttle0-and-dr-code) it sounded like your motherboard's BIOS is becoming corrupted frequently when any setting is changed. This was not fixed by clearing CMOS or flashing/updating BIOS. It is highly likely that your best result will come from doing an RMA (if purchased recently) or simply buying a new mobo.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much jatuttle0 and Moab for assisting me.

So I successfully installed Windows and installed most of the applications, for virtual devices to work in Android Studio I  had to access BIOS (:/) again and I enabled virtualization and saved and exit. I experienced the problem again!! :(

I reinstalled Windows 10 again and enabled virtualization from bios prior installing Windows this time so I wouldn't have to access BIOS to set it.

My problem is, is my BIOS getting corrupted whenever I access it?

PC restarts and shutdown correctly, I don't see a need to access BIOS again for the foreseeable future but if I had to, I'm afraid this problem will pop up again.

Should I flash BIOS?

note : the Tom's hardware thread jatuttle0 mentioned says he flashed BIOS because keyboard and mouse was not working for him, mine are working correctly so I did not attempt to flash BIOS.

Comment: I checked for BIOS updates and there is a new version of the BIOS - F15, http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4150#bios.

My BIOS version is F11 at the moment

Comment: I'd give the update a shot but it sounds like you might be motherboard shopping sometime soon.